# Resample TimeSeries with Deedle C#

Tags: c#, deedle

I'd like to resample a timestamp series using Doodle with C#.
Follow TimeSerie is a signal, acquired at 2Hz frequency (but could be more) and I'd like to resample it at 1Hz frequency and make interpolation when necessary.

```
Timestamp         Channel1
1448869364275310    1800
1448869364775350    1700
1448869365284910    1716
1448869365785650    1692
1448869366295300    1756
1448869366795510    1780
```

Here's my code:

```
System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
                DateTime dt = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(1448869364275310) / 1000000.0);
List<DateTime> lt = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{
   DateTime dt1 = dt.AddSeconds(i);
   lt.Add(dt1);
}

var frame = Frame.ReadCsv(@"C:\\ff.csv",true,true,null,null,"\t",null,null,null);
var frameDate = frame.IndexRows<object>("Timestamp").SortRowsByKey();
var ser = frame.GetColumn<Decimal>("Channel1").Sample(lt.ToOrdinalSeries().Keys);
```

This code just cut values at index corresponding to 1 Hz without making any changes to channel1 values, no resample, no interpolation. 
How to make LinearSpline, CubicSpline?
Please, anybody could help me?

Thanks a lot in advance